# What is the best solution for checking multiple URL parameters with multiple values in a method?

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing

In my Laravel Application I have a simple API Endpoint. Something like this:

```
Route::get('/products/get&organization_id={organization_id}&warehouse_id={warehouse_id?}&stock={stock}', 'ProductController@getProducts');
```

In my controller I have this method:

```
public function getProducts($organizationId = NULL, $warehouseId = 0, $stock)
```

Here I will have some `if`s and some `isset` for the parameters but also a `switch`. (basic validation)

Everything from here is connected to the Repository and the Contract.

My question is where should I do the validation for the parameters and how? Which is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is an extension method on a controller.

In your `getProducts(Request $request)` method, you can do:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'organizationId' => 'required|unique',
    'warehouseId' => 'required',
    'stock' => 'required',
]);
```

Notice, in the getProducts method, we passed in the `Request $request` and not the individual parameters. Request $request obtains all $_POST and $_GET variables and attributes from the query string can be obtained via the request.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for the quick-awesome solution. Should I add the validation in the controller or in the repository?

Comment: Usually in the controller. The controller by default gets the `ValidatesRequests` trait, which is what the `$this.validates` method uses.